# Realizing probability measure preserving actions as isometric actions

Tags: group-actions, ergodic-theory, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $\Gamma\curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ be a probability measure preserving action of a countable group $\Gamma$ on a standard probability space $(X,\mu)$.

It is well known that $X$ can be equipped with a compact topology so that the action is by homeomorphisms. My question is: Can $X$ be equipped with a metric so that the action is by isometries?

Clearly, in general one cannot wish for a compact metric space since there are groups (minimally almost periodic) that have no non-trivial actions by isometries on compact metric spaces. But perhaps one could get some non-compact metric?

Comment: You certainly want to assume some compatibility between the metric and the initial structure of probability space.

Comment: if the action is free, you can just put the discrete metric, right?

Comment: Sorry, of course I mean that the topology induced by the metric generates the original standard Borel structure, so in particular the original measure is Borel with respect to the Borel structure induced by the metric.